# Type constructor as argument to expression

Tags: haskell

I'm using hspec and QuickCheck to validate functor laws for instances of Functor. I have functions

```
functorIdentity :: (Functor f, Eq (f a)) => f a -> Bool
```

and

```
functorComposition :: (Functor f, Eq (f c)) => (Fun a b) -> (Fun b c) -> f a -> Bool
```

I'm then testing these two using blocks of code like this:

```
testListFunctorness :: IO ()
testListFunctorness =
  hspec $ do
    describe "list" $ do
      it "should obey functor identity" $ do
        property (functorIdentity :: [Int] -> Bool)
      it "should obey functor composition" $ do
        property
          (functorComposition :: (Fun Int String) -> (Fun String Int) -> [Int] -> Bool)
```

The thing is, to test the same properties for a different Functor instance, I need to copy everything except the `[Int]`s:

```
testMaybeFunctorness :: IO ()
testMaybeFunctorness =
  hspec $ do
    describe "maybe" $ do
      it "should obey functor identity" $ do
        property (functorIdentity :: Maybe Int -> Bool)
      it "should obey functor composition" $ do
        property
          (functorComposition :: (Fun Int String) -> (Fun String Int) -> Maybe Int -> Bool)
```

It feels like I should be able to write an expression which is in some way polymorphic over different `Functor` instances, but I can't even think how to begin that.

How can I conveniently reuse that block of test logic for multiple different `Functor`s?

Comment: I'm 99% sure I have an AB problem here but I can't see what the B is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is to explicitly pass the desired type to `testFunctorness`:

```hs
import Data.Proxy

testFunctorness :: forall a. Functor a => Proxy a -> IO ()
testFunctorness _ =
  hspec $ do
    describe "the type" $ do
      it "should obey functor identity" $ do
        property (functorIdentity :: a Int -> Bool)
      it "should obey functor composition" $ do
        property
          (functorComposition :: (Fun Int String) -> (Fun String Int) -> a Int -> Bool)
```

The call would look like `testFunctorness (Proxy :: Proxy [])`.

You will need to enable `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` so that the `a` inside the function refers to the `a` in the type signature. The `forall` is then needed to let the typechecker know this `a` should be lexically scoped.

Comment: Ah, Data.Proxy is great. I ended up with `Arbitrary (a Int), Show (a Int), Eq (a Int)` in my constraints to get QuickCheck going, but apart from that it's perfect.